# How to add caption using django-tables2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

ive been trying to get the model name "Cars" on top of my html table, cant, according to bootstrap i can use a tag called "caption" but i don't how to create my own tag.
ive tried adding it via attrs but its not where it should be.
edit

view
def carDetails(request, carlID):

```
if  request.user.is_authenticated():

        car= Car.objects.values().filter(pk=carlID)            

        table = carTable(car)

        return render(request, 'parcelmanager/details.html', {'car': table,)
```

html file

```
  .......
    {% render_table Car %}
    </body>
```

tables

```
class carTable(tables.Table):
class Meta:
fields = ['owner','age','Type']
model = Cars
```

model

```
class Cars(models.Model):
carID = models.CharField(primary_key)

owner = models.CharField()
.......
Type = CharField()
```

im getting i want but i would like the model name to appear above the html table

Comment: Show the code you are using in your html file and how are you passing model name.

Comment: added it, what i want is the ability to add captions to my html by giving my own tag is this possible?

Comment: How you are passing cars to html please also include `views.py` file

Comment: @RajanChauhan sorry for the late response but here it is!